# SSIS Multiple expressions separated by Pipe (|)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

Currently have the following expression:

```
@[TMS_Dest] + "\\" + @[TMS_Rename] + (DT_WSTR,4)DatePart("yyyy", GetDate()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DatePart("mm", GetDate()), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DatePart("dd", GetDate()), 2) + ".xls"
```

Which gives me the location and filename to attach to an outgoing email using the Send Mail Task.

Issue is that I want this task to send two files, but when trying to separate the expressions using a pipe | I get the following casting error:

The data type "DT_WSTR" cannot be used with binary operator "|". The type of one or both of the operands is not supported for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.

Am I using the pipe wrong, if not, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to include the pipe in the string? It sounds like the pipe is trying to be interpreted by the expression editor.

"File1.xls" + "|" + "File2.xls"